# Need "one" object, how to use "new"

Tags: c++, new-operator

I wrote;

```
Element element=new Element;
```

I got error;

```
homework.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
homework.cpp:227:29: error: conversion from 'Element*' to non-scalar type 'Element' requested

*** 1 errors, 0 warnings
```

I do not want a pointer or array of elements,

Altough should i write `Element *element= new Element;`.
SOmebody to explain?

EDIT:

Element class:

```
class Element{
  public:
      Element():exists(false){};

      std::string name;
      std::string full_path_name;
      ElementType element_type;
      long element_size;
      bool exists;

  };
```

Comment: You have an extra semicolon after your constructor.

Comment: Why don't you want a pointer?

Comment: i dont know to use pointers very well, it makes seg faults that i can not solve. could you advise a way to see where does memory corruptions happen?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to allocate a dynamic object, it would be

```
Element* element = new Element;
```

Because `new` returns a pointer to the object in the free store. You have to call `delete element` when you're done using the object to prevent memory leaks. If you want to avoid having to manually manage the memory, you can use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Element> element = new Element;
```

And `element` will call `delete` on the pointer automatically when it goes out of scope. However, are you sure you don't want to just create an automatic object?

```
Element element;
```

This creates the object in automatic storage and you don't have to manually deallocate it *or* use smart pointers, and it's a lot faster; it's the best way. (But make sure you don't do `Element element();` which is the prototype for a function, not a variable declaration.)

Comment: In C++11, you can write `Element element{};` which is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

If your object does not need any arguments you can do

```
Element * element=new Element();
```

If your object needs arguments in the constructor they need to be passed by creation

```
Element * element=new Element(argument1, argument2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling:

`Element * element = new Element;`

Will give you a pointer to an element on the heap which you will later need to `delete`.  You can use the members of this with `element->my_member`.

Caling:

`Element element;` will create an object on the stack which will not need to be deleted and will be invalidated when it goes out of scope.  You can use the members of this with `element.my_member`.

Comment: if i write only "Element element; element.somefield=false;" iam getting seg fault on that line. thanks

Comment: There's nothing intrinsically wrong with that, so I'm guessing that there's something either wrong with the constructor of element or with somefield.  Perhaps you should put the details of the class in another question and ask about the seg fault.

Comment: @tuxi: Then something is broken in the `Element` class

Comment: @tuxi You don't have a `somefield` field, what did you actually write?

Comment: Element element; element.exists=false; know program can run in this line seg faults in another place :( i can not know where is the problem

Comment: @tuxi That sounds like heap/stack corruption, that kind of bug is hard to find because the actual crash occurs in innocent code.  Which OS are you running on?

Comment: @tuxi, why are you doing `element.exists = false;` if it's done in the previous line?

Comment: i am on a local linux distibution, has this a difference about seg fault

Comment: @tuxi No just to the advice regarding debugging it, if it was Windows I'd advise app verifier, but I'm not sure about the best debug strategy on Linux.

Comment: i start a new question with all of the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565209/segmentation-fault-strongly-because-of-heap-stack-corruption

Answer (score 0):

By calling `new` you are allocating an object in heap memory, not in stack( in case of `Element element;`, for example).

The correct way is to use `Element *element= new Element();`

This won't allocate memory for multiple objects (in that case you'd written `new[]`)