# Error Creating List in C++

Tags: c++, list, build, console, makefile

I am trying to create a list in c++, but it's giving me error when I build my code.

Here is my code to create my custom list:

```
std::list< osg::ref_ptr<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> > bulletList = new std::list< osg::ref_ptr<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> > ;
```

The error on console it says this:

error: conversion from `‘std::list<osg::ref_ptr<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> >*’` to non-scalar type `‘std::list<osg::ref_ptr<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> >’` requested

How do I do this?

Comment: Same idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564706/need-one-object-how-to-use-new

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem solved adding the "*" to the declaration of the List, C++ is so annoying lol

Comment: I wouldn't call that solved. Rather get rid of the `=` and everything after it except the semicolon. Please get a book. Also consider using `std::vector`. Chances are it outperforms `std::list` for whatever it is you're doing. If anything, I'd say having to repeat that long type name is the annoying part, and you don't have to.

Comment: `C++ is so annoying `  And it will be even more annoying when you discover you have memory leaks because you used your "solution".

Answer (score 2):

As my comment stated, C++ is not Java.

All you need is this:

```
std::list< osg::ref_ptr<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> > bulletList;
```

If for some reason you really wanted to create a list dynamically, then you use a pointer.

```
std::list< osg::ref_ptr<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> >* bulletList = new std::list< osg::ref_ptr<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> >();
```

Then you have the headache now of making sure `delete` is called, else there is a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a std::list<...> not a std::list<...>* so there is no reason to use new to allocate storage for it. The compiler will do this for you.